# How do I know which graphics card is being used in a hybrid system?

Tags: 11.10, acer, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

I have an Acer Aspire 5935G. It comes with hybrid grahics solution from Nvidia. It has two graphic cards; Nvidia GeForce 130GT M (discrete) and Intel mobile graphics series 4. I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 but I get no information about what graphics card the notebook is currently using. Also how can I use only one of them permanently (preferably Intel graphics), while disabling the other?

Comment: What do you get for the output of `lspci | grep VGA` from your terminal? Also did you check this question - [I have a hardware detection problem. What logs do I need to look into?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into)?

Comment: Please make your second question a separate question.

Comment: Your laptop does not use Optimus (which started around 3xxM on some Dells, but officially on 4xxM). It is a [1st gen switchable graphics](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=188130). Can you submit your machine information on [this LP bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lpbugreporter/+bug/752542)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see which video card on my Optimus-enabled machine is being used?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/230746/how-can-i-see-which-video-card-on-my-optimus-enabled-machine-is-being-used)

Answer (score 1):

By default optimus is not supported in ubuntu so you are probably using your intel card if you havent installed bumblebee. if you want to use optimus you can use the bubble bee projects to run particular programs through the nicer nvidia GPU. it uses a virtual framebuffer to reroute the whole thing. Pretty tricky stuff but relatively transparent to the end user.

http://www.bumblebee-project.org/